# Get value from map which is a list/array

Tags: groovy

I'm getting the parameters from a POST request (x-www-form-urlencoded) formatted as below:

```
def postreq = exc?.request
def params = postreq?.getPostParams()
println params

Console:
[request:[foo], client:[abcd], id:[qwert]]
```

How can I use `request` as key and get its value? Note that there is a extra pair of brackets and the strings are not quoted.
I've tried @injecteer suggestions but all I got is `caused by NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'request' on null object`

I could print all key:value pairs by doing

```
params.collect{println it.key.toString() + " " + it.value.toString()}

Console:
request [foo]
client [abcd]
id [qwert]
```

but couldn't get a specific one.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Are the values lists, why the square brackets ? Should have quotes, they're strings:  `['request':'[12345]', 'client':'[abcd]', 'id':'[qwert]']`

Comment: You are stating that something is not working, but you fail to produce what you have tried. So assuming, that there might be more to it, could you please provide a MCVE to show the problem and how the result is not of your liking?

Comment: @Deadpool ``foo``

Comment: @ou_ryperd I don't know why, it's how I'm getting the POST parameters...

Comment: @cfrick updated the post with more info, thanks!

Comment: Then `params.request.first()` should work. If you see NPEs you are not holding in your hand what you think you are holding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had to convert the variable to string then I could print it:

```
def params = postreq?.getPostParams()
def reqobj = params?.request.toString()
println reqobj
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
def map = [request:[12345], client:['abcd'], id:['qwert']]

assert map.request == [12345]                 // dot-notation

assert map[ 'request' ] == [12345]            // subscript operator

def name = 'request'
assert map."${name}" == [12345]               // Groovy's meta-magical String-interpolated dot-notation

assert map.get( 'request' ) == [12345]        // casual java Map's method

assert map.getAt( 'request' ) == [12345]      // Groovy's extension of get()
```

Comment: All I got is ``caused by NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'request' on null object``. I also updated the post with more info. Thanks!

Comment: My script runs successfully on https://groovyconsole.appspot.com . There must be something wrong with the way you are getting the data